# Cannot access app running in Node Docker container until I exec into container

Tags: node.js, bash, docker

So this is weird. I have a Node/React app running in a simple docker container. I cannot get to the web page unless I run `docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash`. Nothing else. execing into he container is enough.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /src/

EXPOSE 3002

COPY . .

# Start the app
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Build Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#if you can't get this to work, try chmod +x build.sh
echo "Building container_name"

CONTAINER_NAME="container_name";
echo $CONTAINER_NAME;

docker stop $CONTAINER_NAME
docker rm $CONTAINER_NAME

cd ../

docker build -f Dockerfile.dev -t $CONTAINER_NAME .

docker run --detach --name ${CONTAINER_NAME} \
    --volume $(pwd)/:/src \
    --publish 3002:3002 \
    ${CONTAINER_NAME}:latest

docker container ls

PORT="$(docker port ${CONTAINER_NAME} | sed 's/.*://')"

echo ""
echo ""
echo "***********************************************"
echo "container_name running on:"
echo "http://localhost:$PORT"
echo "***********************************************"
```

Once I exec into the container I can access localhost:3002. Anyone have any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Which framework you're using, seems like its bind with 127.0.0.1 only

Comment: Node and it delivers a react bundle as well. Why would it start to work when I exec in then?

Comment: because it responding on exec as you are on localhost of container.